# Detect languages in a column, but ignore ambiguous values. Why am i getting an error?

Tags: python, language-detection

Here is a sample dataset:

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Here Are the Details on Facebook's Global Part... |
| 2 | Aktien New York Schluss: Moderate Verluste nac... |
| 3 | ClÃ´ture de Wall Street : Trump plombe la tend... |
| 4 | '' |
| 5 | NaN |

I need to add 'Language' column, which represents what language is used in 'Details' column, so that in the end it will look like this:

| ID | Details | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Here Are the Details on Facebook's Global Part... | en |
| 2 | Aktien New York Schluss: Moderate Verluste nac... | de |
| 3 | ClÃ´ture de Wall Street : Trump plombe la tend... | fr |
| 4 | '' | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN |

I tried this code:

```
!pip install langdetect
from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory
DetectorFactory.seed = 0
df2=df.dropna(subset=['Details'])
df2['Language']=df2['Details'].apply(detect)
```

It failed, I guess it is because of rows that have values like 'ID'=4. Therefore, I tried this:

```
!pip install langdetect
from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory
DetectorFactory.seed = 0
df2=df.dropna(subset=['Details'])
df2['Language']=df2['Details'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) if len(x)>1 else np.NaN)
```

However, I still got an error:

LangDetectException: No features in text.

Comment: Catch the error and return NaN from the function you apply. Note that you can give _any_ callable as the argument to `.apply()`, doesn't have to be a lambda

Comment: i am sorry, didn't really get what do you mean. can you show me a code, so that i understand, please? thank you @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error and return `NaN` from the function you apply. Note that you can give *any* callable that takes one input and returns one output as the argument to `.apply()`, it doesn't have to be a lambda

```
def detect_lang(x):
    if len(x) <= 1: return np.nan 
    try:
        lang = detect(x)
        if lang: return lang # Return lang if lang is not empty
    except langdetect.LangDetectException:
        pass # Don't do anything when you get an error, so you can fall through to the next line, which returns a Nan
    return np.nan  # If lang was empty or there was an error, we reach this line

df2['Language']=df2['Details].apply(detect_lang)
```

I'm not sure why you had `if len(x)>1` in there: that would only return `NaN` when the *original string* has zero or one characters, but I included it in my `detect_lang` function to keep the functionality consistent with your lambda.